# add shapefile with JS sample code

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

i want to add shapefile to the map from the folder. i have used JS sample code but it does not work for me.it gives error in response , featurecollection . it doesnot got into request block so i change it to esri request but still code not working

```
  var portalUrl = "https://www.arcgis.com";

          esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
          on(dojo.byId("uploadForm"), "change", function (event) {
            var fileName = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

          <!-- if (sniff("ie")) { //filename is full path in IE so extract the file name -->
              <!-- var arr = fileName.split("\\"); -->
              <!-- fileName = arr[arr.length - 1]; -->
            <!-- } -->
            if (fileName.indexOf(".zip") !== -1) {//is file a zip - if not notify user
              generateFeatureCollection(fileName);
            }
            else {
              alert("Add shapefile as .zip file");
            }
          });


          function generateFeatureCollection (fileName) {
            var name = fileName.split(".");
            name = name[0].replace("c:\\fakepath\\", "");

            var params = {
              'name': name,
              'targetSR': map.spatialReference,
              'maxRecordCount': 1000,
              'enforceInputFileSizeLimit': true,
              'enforceOutputJsonSizeLimit': true
            };

            //var extent = scaleUtils.getExtentForScale(map, 40000);
            var extent = esri.geometry.getExtentForScale(map, 40000);
            var resolution = extent.getWidth() / map.width;
            params.generalize = true;
            params.maxAllowableOffset = resolution;
            params.reducePrecision = true;
            params.numberOfDigitsAfterDecimal = 0;

                       var myContent = {
              'filetype': 'shapefile',
              'publishParameters': JSON.stringify(params),
              'f': 'json',
              //'callback.html': 'textarea'
            };

            esriRequest({
              url: portalUrl + '/sharing/rest/content/features/generate',
              content: myContent,
               form: dojo.byId('uploadForm'),
              handleAs: 'json',
              load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
                <!-- if (response.error) { -->
                  <!-- errorHandler(response.error); -->
                  <!-- return; -->
                <!-- } -->

                var layerName = response.FeatureCollection.layers[0].layerDefinition.name;

                addShapefileToMap(response.FeatureCollection);
              }),
             //error: lang.hitch(this, errorHandler)
            });
          }

          function addShapefileToMap (featureCollection) {

            var fullExtent;
            var layers = [];

            arrayUtils.forEach(featureCollection.layers, function (layer) {
              var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Details", "${*}");
              var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(layer, {
                infoTemplate: infoTemplate
              });

              featureLayer.on('click', function (event) {
                map.infoWindow.setFeatures([event.graphic]);
              });
              changeRenderer(featureLayer);
              fullExtent = fullExtent ?
                fullExtent.union(featureLayer.fullExtent) : featureLayer.fullExtent;
              layers.push(featureLayer);
            });
            map.addLayers(layers);
            map.setExtent(fullExtent.expand(1.25), true);

          }

          function changeRenderer (layer) {
            //change the default symbol for the feature collection for polygons and points
            var symbol = null;
            switch (layer.geometryType) {
              case 'esriGeometryPoint':
                symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({
                  'angle': 0,
                  'xoffset': 0,
                  'yoffset': 0,
                  'type': 'esriPMS',
                  'url': 'https://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/BluePin1LargeB.png',
                  'contentType': 'image/png',
                  'width': 20,
                  'height': 20
                });
                break;
              case 'esriGeometryPolygon':
                symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                  new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                    new Color([112, 112, 112]), 1), new Color([136, 136, 136, 0.25]));
                break;
            }
            if (symbol) {
              layer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(symbol));
            }

}
```

Comment: do u have a valid shape file.. it it possible to share here....?

Comment: i have used dummy shapefile of austri

Comment: any solution?  i am getting error : arrayUtils is not a function

Comment: did u require arrayUtils on top? check the sequence of the require element. or add complete code that will show require part as well in above code...

Comment: Usually we get this error when arrayUtils  is not required or sequence is wrong of required component....

Comment: can you create a running sample where i can reproduce the error.. then it will be easier to tell u the exact error...

Comment: no i used array in the require. but when i change arrayUtils to array i got error Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f2hxt25d/2/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I went through your jsfiddle and atteched code, I observed few items is missing in it-

1. important links and js libraries.
2. dojo /esri component require
3. map element to display shapefile
4. map control html to load map element.

**Below is the working code**(try this)-

```js
 var map;

      require([
        "esri/config",
        "esri/InfoTemplate",
        "esri/map",
        "esri/request",
        "esri/geometry/scaleUtils",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
        "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/json",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/sniff",
        "dojo/_base/array",
        "esri/Color",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ],
        function (
        esriConfig, InfoTemplate, Map, request, scaleUtils, FeatureLayer,
        SimpleRenderer, PictureMarkerSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
        dom, JSON, on, parser, sniff, arrayUtils, Color, lang
      ) {

          parser.parse();

var portalUrl = "https://www.arcgis.com";

          esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
    on(dojo.byId("uploadForm"), "change", function (event) {
            var fileName = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    
    <!-- if (sniff("ie")) { //filename is full path in IE so extract the file name -->
              <!-- var arr = fileName.split("\\"); -->
              <!-- fileName = arr[arr.length - 1]; -->
            <!-- } -->
            if (fileName.indexOf(".zip") !== -1) {//is file a zip - if not notify user
              generateFeatureCollection(fileName);
            }
            else {
              alert("Add shapefile as .zip file");
            }
          });
    
       map = new Map("mapCanvas", {
            basemap: "gray",
            center: [-41.647, 36.41],
            zoom: 3,
            slider: false
          });
    
    function generateFeatureCollection (fileName) {
            var name = fileName.split(".");
   name = name[0].replace("c:\\fakepath\\", "");
              
   var params = {
              'name': name,
              'targetSR': map.spatialReference,
              'maxRecordCount': 1000,
              'enforceInputFileSizeLimit': true,
              'enforceOutputJsonSizeLimit': true
            };
           
   //var extent = scaleUtils.getExtentForScale(map, 40000);
   var extent = esri.geometry.getExtentForScale(map, 40000);
            var resolution = extent.getWidth() / map.width;
            params.generalize = true;
            params.maxAllowableOffset = resolution;
            params.reducePrecision = true;
            params.numberOfDigitsAfterDecimal = 0;
           
     
            var myContent = {
              'filetype': 'shapefile',
              'publishParameters': json.stringify(params),
              'f': 'json',
              'callback.html': 'textarea'
            };
   
   esriRequest({
              url: portalUrl + '/sharing/rest/content/features/generate',
              content: myContent,
               form: dojo.byId('uploadForm'),
              handleAs: 'json',
              load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                  errorHandler(response.error);
                  return;
                }
    var featureCollection = {
          "layerDefinition": null,
          "featureSet": {
            "features": [],
            "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint"
          }
        };
                var layerName = response.featureCollection.layers[0].layerDefinition.name;
                
                addShapefileToMap(response.featureCollection);
              }),
             //error: lang.hitch(this, errorHandler)
            });
          }
    
    function addShapefileToMap (featureCollection) {
           
            var fullExtent;
            var layers = [];

           array.forEach(featureCollection.layers, function (layer) {
   //for(var i = 0 ; i<=featureCollection.layers.length ; i++){
   //featureCollection.layers.forEach(function(layer){

   var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Details", "${*}");
              var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(layer, {
                infoTemplate: infoTemplate
              });
              
              featureLayer.on('click', function (event) {
                map.infoWindow.setFeatures([event.graphic]);
              });
              changeRenderer(featureLayer);
              fullExtent = fullExtent ?
                fullExtent.union(featureLayer.fullExtent) : featureLayer.fullExtent;
              layers.push(featureLayer);
            });
            map.addLayers(layers);
            map.setExtent(fullExtent.expand(1.25), true);

          }
          
    function changeRenderer (layer) {
            //change the default symbol for the feature collection for polygons and points
            var symbol = null;
            switch (layer.geometryType) {
              case 'esriGeometryPoint':
                symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({
                  'angle': 0,
                  'xoffset': 0,
                  'yoffset': 0,
                  'type': 'esriPMS',
                  'url': 'https://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/BluePin1LargeB.png',
                  'contentType': 'image/png',
                  'width': 20,
                  'height': 20
                });
                break;
              case 'esriGeometryPolygon':
                symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                  new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                    new Color([112, 112, 112]), 1), new Color([136, 136, 136, 0.25]));
                break;
            }
            if (symbol) {
              layer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(symbol));
            }

}
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fileupload.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/css/esri.css">

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="uploadForm">
              <div class="field">
                  <label class="file-upload">
                      <!-- <span><strong>Choose File</strong></span> -->
       <!-- <span align = "center"><Add Shapefile></span> -->
       <Label style="font-weight: bold; align = center ">Add Shapefile</label><br></br>
                      <input type="file" name="file" id="inFile" />
                  </label>
              </div>
              </form>
              <span class="file-upload-status" style="opacity:1;" id="upload-status"></span>
              <div id="fileInfo">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="mapCanvas" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
```

**Updated JSFiddle-** https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/f2hxt25d/4/

**Note-** If still its causing problem then share your shapefile.

**Hoping this will help you.**

Comment: thansk but i have added all these thing u have mentioned. but your code also does not upload file. no i have got error : Color is not a constructor :(

Comment: i told you i am using dummy shapefile . i have downloaded from internet

Comment: polygon shapefile, boundary shapefile

Comment: send me the link from where you downloaded it.. otherwise have to create a shapefile manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Tried to create another sample-

**Here is the working example -**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>


   
    <title>Add Shapefile</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/portal_addshapefile/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/portal_addshapefile/css/fileupload.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/css/esri.css">

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;

      require([
        "esri/config",
        "esri/InfoTemplate",
        "esri/map",
        "esri/request",
        "esri/geometry/scaleUtils",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
        "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/json",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/sniff",
        "dojo/_base/array",
        "esri/Color",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ],
        function (
        esriConfig, InfoTemplate, Map, request, scaleUtils, FeatureLayer,
        SimpleRenderer, PictureMarkerSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
        dom, JSON, on, parser, sniff, arrayUtils, Color, lang
      ) {

          parser.parse();

          var portalUrl = "https://www.arcgis.com";

          //esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";

          on(dom.byId("uploadForm"), "change", function (event) {
            var fileName = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

            if (sniff("ie")) { //filename is full path in IE so extract the file name
              var arr = fileName.split("\\");
              fileName = arr[arr.length - 1];
            }
            if (fileName.indexOf(".zip") !== -1) {//is file a zip - if not notify user
              generateFeatureCollection(fileName);
            }
            else {
              dom.byId('upload-status').innerHTML = '<p style="color:red">Add shapefile as .zip file</p>';
            }
          });

          map = new Map("mapCanvas", {
            basemap: "gray",
            center: [-41.647, 36.41],
            zoom: 3,
            slider: false
          });

          function generateFeatureCollection (fileName) {
            var name = fileName.split(".");
            //Chrome and IE add c:\fakepath to the value - we need to remove it
            //See this link for more info: http://davidwalsh.name/fakepath
            name = name[0].replace("c:\\fakepath\\", "");

            dom.byId('upload-status').innerHTML = '<b>Loading… </b>' + name;

            //Define the input params for generate see the rest doc for details
            //http://www.arcgis.com/apidocs/rest/index.html?generate.html
            var params = {
              'name': name,
              'targetSR': map.spatialReference,
              'maxRecordCount': 1000,
              'enforceInputFileSizeLimit': true,
              'enforceOutputJsonSizeLimit': true
            };

            //generalize features for display Here we generalize at 1:40,000 which is approx 10 meters
            //This should work well when using web mercator.
            var extent = scaleUtils.getExtentForScale(map, 40000);
            var resolution = extent.getWidth() / map.width;
            params.generalize = true;
            params.maxAllowableOffset = resolution;
            params.reducePrecision = true;
            params.numberOfDigitsAfterDecimal = 0;

            var myContent = {
              'filetype': 'shapefile',
              'publishParameters': JSON.stringify(params),
              'f': 'json',
              'callback.html': 'textarea'
            };

            //use the rest generate operation to generate a feature collection from the zipped shapefile
            request({
              url: portalUrl + '/sharing/rest/content/features/generate',
              content: myContent,
              form: dom.byId('uploadForm'),
              handleAs: 'json',
              load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                  errorHandler(response.error);
                  return;
                }
                var layerName = response.featureCollection.layers[0].layerDefinition.name;
                dom.byId('upload-status').innerHTML = '<b>Loaded: </b>' + layerName;
                addShapefileToMap(response.featureCollection);
              }),
              error: lang.hitch(this, errorHandler)
            });
          }

          function errorHandler (error) {
            dom.byId('upload-status').innerHTML =
            "<p style='color:red'>" + error.message + "</p>";
          }

          function addShapefileToMap (featureCollection) {
            //add the shapefile to the map and zoom to the feature collection extent
            //If you want to persist the feature collection when you reload browser you could store the collection in
            //local storage by serializing the layer using featureLayer.toJson()  see the 'Feature Collection in Local Storage' sample
            //for an example of how to work with local storage.
            var fullExtent;
            var layers = [];

            arrayUtils.forEach(featureCollection.layers, function (layer) {
              var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Details", "${*}");
              var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(layer, {
                infoTemplate: infoTemplate
              });
              //associate the feature with the popup on click to enable highlight and zoom to
              featureLayer.on('click', function (event) {
                map.infoWindow.setFeatures([event.graphic]);
              });
              //change default symbol if desired. Comment this out and the layer will draw with the default symbology
              changeRenderer(featureLayer);
              fullExtent = fullExtent ?
                fullExtent.union(featureLayer.fullExtent) : featureLayer.fullExtent;
              layers.push(featureLayer);
            });
            map.addLayers(layers);
            map.setExtent(fullExtent.expand(1.25), true);

            dom.byId('upload-status').innerHTML = "";
          }

          function changeRenderer (layer) {
            //change the default symbol for the feature collection for polygons and points
            var symbol = null;
            switch (layer.geometryType) {
              case 'esriGeometryPoint':
                symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({
                  'angle': 0,
                  'xoffset': 0,
                  'yoffset': 0,
                  'type': 'esriPMS',
                  'url': 'https://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/BluePin1LargeB.png',
                  'contentType': 'image/png',
                  'width': 20,
                  'height': 20
                });
                break;
              case 'esriGeometryPolygon':
                symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                  new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                    new Color([112, 112, 112]), 1), new Color([136, 136, 136, 0.25]));
                break;
            }
            if (symbol) {
              layer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(symbol));
            }
          }
        });
    </script>

  <body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline',gutters:false" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="rightPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'">
        <div style='padding-left:4px;'>
          <p>
            Add a zipped shapefile to the map.</p><p>Visit the
            <a target='_blank' href="https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/shapefiles.htm">Shapefiles</a> help topic for information and limitations.</p>
              <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="uploadForm">
              <div class="field">
                  <label class="file-upload">
                      <span><strong>Add File</strong></span>
                      <input type="file" name="file" id="inFile" />
                  </label>
              </div>
              </form>
              <span class="file-upload-status" style="opacity:1;" id="upload-status"></span>
              <div id="fileInfo">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mapCanvas" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Updated JSFiddle Link-**https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/Lrsrdojh/2/

I tried with with following Shapefile-
[image]

**Source:-** https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=portal_addshapefile

**Hoping this will finally solve your issue!**

Comment: i have followed this sample. anyways i am trying to solve my  problem

Comment: can any one tell me why i am getting this error on one shapefile it gives me error Tried to register widget with id==dijit_layout_AccordionContainer_0 but that id is already registered

on other shapefile it gives error time out exceeds. i am using the same sample code i do not understands why it gives error

Comment: the timeout exceeded error we got when we were uploading a very large shape file.. keep the same code and try with the same shapefile which i used. and check that....

Comment: create custom graphics on the map and save as shapefile using this website http://geojson.io .... then upload this shapefile.. are you still getting the same error after uploading this new shapefile...

Comment: great.. cool I am glad.. post your answer here that may help others too...